# execute immediate alter sequence not working

Tags: oracle, plsql, sequence, execute-immediate

I'm stuck on this pretty simple script. It isn't working like I expect it to.

```
declare
 st VARCHAR(1024);
begin
  for x in (SELECT sequence_name FROM USER_SEQUENCES) loop
      st := 'ALTER SEQUENCE ' || x.sequence_name ||  ' INCREMENT BY 1000';
      execute immediate st;
      st := 'select ' || x.sequence_name ||  '.nextval from dual';
      execute immediate st;
      st := 'ALTER SEQUENCE ' || x.sequence_name ||  ' INCREMENT BY 1';
      execute immediate st;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

When I run this it doesn't appear to work at all - all of my sequences just stay as they are, and they have not been incremented by a thousand by the dynamic statements. If I check `nextval` before and after the anonymous block, the difference is only 1, not 1001.

If I replace `execute immediate` with `dbms_output.put_line` and execute the generated commands manually the sequences are altered as I want.

What am I missing?

Comment: I believe this will work for you.
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:951269671592

Comment: What results are you getting, and what results did you expect?

Comment: What version are you using?  In 12c there is a slightly easier way to do this.

Comment: @JonHeller, i'm using 12c, how can I do this on this version ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Both `alter sequence` statements are working, it's the increment in between that isn't happening.  The `nextval` call in your loop is not being evaluated because the select statement isn't sending its output anywhere. From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/executeimmediate_statement.htm#LNPLS1201), a note that happens to refer to exactly what you are doing:

> **Note:**
>   If *dynamic_sql_statement* is a `SELECT` statement, and you omit both *into_clause* and *bulk_collect_into_clause*, then *execute_immediate_statement* never executes.
>   For example, this statement never increments the sequence:
>
> ```
> EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT S.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL'
> ```

So you need to select that value into something:

```
declare
 st VARCHAR(1024);
 val number;
begin
  for x in (SELECT sequence_name FROM USER_SEQUENCES) loop
      st := 'ALTER SEQUENCE ' || x.sequence_name ||  ' INCREMENT BY 1000';
      execute immediate st;
      st := 'select ' || x.sequence_name ||  '.nextval from dual';
      execute immediate st into val;
      st := 'ALTER SEQUENCE ' || x.sequence_name ||  ' INCREMENT BY 1';
      execute immediate st;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

I've added a `val` variable, and an `into val` clause on the second execute immediate.

To demonstrate that it works now:

```
create sequence s42;

Sequence s42 created.

declare
 st VARCHAR(1024);
 n number;
begin
  for x in (SELECT sequence_name FROM USER_SEQUENCES) loop
      st := 'ALTER SEQUENCE ' || x.sequence_name ||  ' INCREMENT BY 1000';
      execute immediate st;
      st := 'select ' || x.sequence_name ||  '.nextval from dual';
      execute immediate st into n;
      st := 'ALTER SEQUENCE ' || x.sequence_name ||  ' INCREMENT BY 1';
      execute immediate st;
  end loop;
end;
/

anonymous block completed

select s42.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
      1001
```

Without the `into` clause, this came back with 1 rather than 1001, which is what you are seeing.

Answer (score 3):

The `restart start with` syntax in 12c can simplify the steps:

```
create sequence test_sequence;

declare
 st VARCHAR(1024);
begin
  for x in (SELECT sequence_name, last_number FROM USER_SEQUENCES) loop
      st := 'ALTER SEQUENCE ' || x.sequence_name
          || ' RESTART START WITH ' || to_char(x.last_number+1000);
      execute immediate st;
  end loop;
end;
/

select test_sequence.nextval from dual;

NEXTVAL
-------
   1001
```