# Getting min value of the sequence

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sequence

I have around 100 sequences defined in the database, that are set to some number after the testing has been performed.

For example: 
There is a sequence: suppier_seq. 
That would start with 1 and now its currval is 101.

I need to reset all the sequences that exist based on their min value.

If I extract the DDL of the sequence, it comes with the present value as start with:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  "RMS14"."SUPPLIER_SEQUENCE"  MINVALUE 0 MAXVALUE 99999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 101 CACHE 100 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
```

I need to restart the sequence with the minimum value.

How can i capture the minimum value of the sequence via SQL?

Comment: With the MINVALUE it was originally created with, or the START WITH? The *original* START WITH isn't stored anyway, so are you assuming you want to start with MINVALUE + 1? Can't you drop and recreate them from your controlled DDL scripts - you have those in source control, right?

Comment: Have a read of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51470/how-do-i-reset-a-sequence-in-oracle)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't tell what the sequence's original `START WITH` value was. You can only base it on the `MINVALUE`, either using that (even if it's zero), or adding one to it, or only doing that if it's non-zero.

You can get the current values for your own sequences from the `user_sequences` view, and use a PL/SQL block to loop over them, generating drop and create statements on the way:

```
set serveroutput on
begin
  for r in (
    select 'DROP SEQUENCE "' || sequence_name || '"' as drop_stmt,
      'CREATE SEQUENCE "' || sequence_name || '"'
        || ' MINVALUE ' || min_value
        || ' MAXVALUE ' || max_value
        || ' INCREMENT BY ' || increment_by
        || ' START WITH ' || min_value
        || case when cache_size = 0 then ' NOCACHE' else ' CACHE ' || cache_size end
        || case when order_flag = 'Y' then ' ORDER' else ' NOORDER' end
        || case when cycle_flag = 'Y' then ' CYCLE' else ' NOCYCLE' end
        as create_stmt
    from user_sequences
  )
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(r.drop_stmt);
--    execute immediate r.drop_stmt;
    dbms_output.put_line(r.create_stmt);
--    execute immediate r.create_stmt;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

I've left the `execute immediate` statement commented out to try to avoid accidents from this being copied and pasted without any checks; initially it will just display the commands it would run, e.g.

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

DROP SEQUENCE "SUPPLIER_SEQUENCE"
CREATE SEQUENCE "SUPPLIER_SEQUENCE" MINVALUE 0 MAXVALUE 99999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 0 CACHE 100 NOORDER NOCYCLE
...
```

If you're working in another schema and have the right permissions you can query 
`all_sequences` or `dba_sequences` instead, and specify the owner:

```
    select 'DROP SEQUENCE "' || sequence_owner || '"."' || sequence_name ||'"' as drop_stmt,
      'CREATE SEQUENCE "' || sequence_owner || '"."' || sequence_name || '"'
        || ' MINVALUE ' || min_value
...
```

Another approach is to alter the sequence to set the `INCREMENT BY` to *minus* the current highest value (or the highest value minus the `MINVALUE`), call `nextval`, and then reset the increment. That's a bit messy dynamically, not least because you need a second level on dynamic statement to get the current sequence value when it's done directly in a loop like this, but basically the same idea:

```
declare
  l_nextval number;
begin
  for r in (
    select 'BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ''ALTER SEQUENCE "' || sequence_name || '"'
        || ' INCREMENT BY -''|| ("' || sequence_name || '".nextval - ' || min_value ||'); END;'
        as alter_stmt_1,
      'SELECT "' || sequence_name || '".nextval from dual' as adjust_stmt,
      'ALTER SEQUENCE "' || sequence_name || '"'
        || ' INCREMENT BY ' || increment_by
        as alter_stmt_2
    from user_sequences
  )
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(r.alter_stmt_1);
--    execute immediate r.alter_stmt_1;
    dbms_output.put_line(r.adjust_stmt);
--    execute immediate r.adjust_stmt into l_nextval;
    dbms_output.put_line(r.alter_stmt_2);
--    execute immediate r.alter_stmt_2;
  end loop;
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SEQUENCE "SUPPLIER_SEQUENCE" INCREMENT BY -'|| ("SUPPLIER_SEQUENCE".nextval - 0); END;
SELECT "SUPPLIER_SEQUENCE".nextval from dual
ALTER SEQUENCE "SUPPLIER_SEQUENCE" INCREMENT BY 1
```

You could also generate the dynamic statements inside the loop, which is perhaps a bit neater for this approach:

```
declare
  l_alter_stmt_1 varchar2(4000);
  l_alter_stmt_2 varchar2(4000);
  l_adjust_stmt varchar2(4000);
  l_nextval number;
begin
  for r in (select * from user_sequences) loop
    l_adjust_stmt := 'select "' || r.sequence_name || '".nextval from dual';
    execute immediate l_adjust_stmt into l_nextval;
    l_alter_stmt_1 := 'ALTER SEQUENCE "' || r.sequence_name || '"'
        || ' INCREMENT BY '|| (r.min_value - l_nextval);
    l_alter_stmt_2 := 'ALTER SEQUENCE "' || r.sequence_name || '"'
        || ' INCREMENT BY ' || r.increment_by;
    dbms_output.put_line(l_alter_stmt_1);
--    execute immediate r.alter_stmt_1;
    dbms_output.put_line(l_adjust_stmt);
--    execute immediate l_adjust_stmt into l_nextval;
    dbms_output.put_line(l_alter_stmt_2);
--    execute immediate l_alter_stmt_2;
  end loop;
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

ALTER SEQUENCE "SUPPLIER_SEQUENCE" INCREMENT BY -101
select "SUPPLIER_SEQUENCE".nextval from dual
ALTER SEQUENCE "SUPPLIER_SEQUENCE" INCREMENT BY 1
```

The question is specifically about 11g, but [this is even simpler in 12c](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28714053/266304).